# jQuery UI Datepicker - Disable Holidays and Saturdays - Add Friday

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

My Datepicker currently disables holidays and weekends. I'm trying to add Fridays to the script

```
var holidays = <?php echo $holidays; ?>;
// var holidays =[ [2020,01,01,'New Years Day'],[2020,04,21,'My Birthday'],[2020,12,25,'Christmas Day'] ];

function setHolidays(date) {
    for (i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {
        if (date.getFullYear() == holidays[i][0]
            && date.getMonth() == holidays[i][1] - 1
            && date.getDate() == holidays[i][2]) {
            return [false, 'holiday', holidays[i][3]];
        }
    }
    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    return !noWeekend[0] ? noWeekend : [true];
}

$( ".add_delivery_date").datepicker( {          
    firstDay: 0,
    beforeShowDay: setHolidays
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another check in the `setHolidays` function to check the date for Friday.

I added the check just after the loop on the holidays array:

```js
//var holidays = <?php echo $holidays; ?>;
 var holidays =[ [2020,01,01,'New Years Day'],[2020,04,21,'My Birthday'],[2020,12,25,'Christmas Day'] ];

function setHolidays(date) {
    for (i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {
        if (date.getFullYear() == holidays[i][0]
            && date.getMonth() == holidays[i][1] - 1
            && date.getDate() == holidays[i][2]) {
            return [false, 'holiday', holidays[i][3]];
        }
    }

    if (date.getDay() === 5) { // No Friday's
        return [false, '', ''];
    }

    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    return !noWeekend[0] ? noWeekend : [true];
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $( ".add_delivery_date").datepicker( {          
      firstDay: 0,
      beforeShowDay: setHolidays
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

Date:  <input type="text" class="add_delivery_date"> <br />
```